# すげえまずい expression meaning

Tags: translation, slang, spoken-language

what is the meaning of the expression すげえまずい alone?

I've never read it before.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すげえまずい <= すごいまずい <= すごくまずい i.e. gross/really awful tasting.

As for the change すごい => すげえ, you might be aware of, for example, いらない => いらねえ, both of which are very informal.

P.S. Since you provide no context, I assumed that まずい refers to food. まずい is used in other contexts, so you may have to adjust the translation accordingly.

Comment: ありがとうございます！Very Helpful!