# Is 情けねえ the negative form of 情け?

Tags: usage, nuances, negation

And if so, how is this negative (情けねえ) different from 情けない?

Comment: I believe ねえ here is the same as ない. It's often being used by the guy. I saw a lot of it on light novel texts.

Comment: This must be a frequent question here. I found this answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/%e3%81%99%e3%81%92%e3%81%88%e3%81%be%e3%81%9a%e3%81%84-expression-meaning